Increase number of parallel scenarios in behaviourSpace
I am using netlogo 6.4.0. When I set a runs through behaviourSpace it reads that it can run in parallel between 18 and 24 scenarios. I read that I can change the ram amount it has access to in the netlogo cfg files and restart for better performance of the interface, presumably increase number of parallel runs. I changed the netlogo cft file from 50% to 80%. There is no guide that indicates which of the 4-5 cfg fules should be changed. I was hoping or thinking that changing that file the way I did meant that now it has access to 80% of my pc ram (16GB). However, after saving that change and restart netlogo, it still saying I can only run 18-24 scenarios in parallel.
Am I doing it wrong? Is this method if allocating more ram is the way to increase the number of parallel runs?

The number of runs you can do in parallel in BehaviorSpace is limited by your computer hardware. You should select a number of runs up to the number of processors your computer has. (My laptop's CPU has 2 cores, each with 2 processors, so I can execute up to 4 BehaviorSpace runs at once.)
So-increasing the RAM available to NetLogo is a good idea because each run uses more RAM; but it does not change the number of runs executed at once.
If you are not sure how many processors you have, and you are in Windows, open at Task Manager and click on the tab "Performance". It will tell you how many cores and "logical processors" you have. If you leave the Task Manager open when you start  BehaviorSpace, you will see how much of your processing ability it uses.

Thank you for that answer. Sorry for the late somewhat reply (was off grid kinda).
So if I understand it correct, if I will get me lets say an Azure VM with 32 or 64 vCPUs and 256GB of RAM I could do better in terms of parallel runs and the time it will take to process each batch?
